# Copy, Paste Automation

Tags: c#, automation, copy-paste

How can I paste text at the windows cursor position?
I created an application in which I have one rich box and one button, and on that button when I click it simply paste the text at any location of window's cursor.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to press a button and then have your clipboard contents pasted in the first instance your cursor touches something that allows for text input in your window. I'd have a boolean that is set to true when the button is clicked, allowing clipboard contents to be paste into a text field.

This should work for WPF and WinForms, here is a small example I come up with:

[image: Example of copy, paste automation]

```cs
// Use this to see if paste automation is on or not.
private bool pasteOnTextBoxHover = false;

private void btnPasteAutomation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Turn paste automation on
    this.pasteOnTextBoxHover = true;
}

private void rtbPasteBox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (pasteOnTextBoxHover) {
         // Get contents of clipboard and put it in the textbox
         rtbPasteBox.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
         // Turn paste automation back off until button is pressed again
         pasteOnTextBoxHover = false;
     }     
}
```